# Tcl upvar issue

Tags: tcl, upvar

Im trying to modify a variable using upvar (in an upward stack), but the value of the variable is passed to the procedure and not the variable name.

**I cannot change what is passed**, since it is already implemented widely on the program.

Is there a way to modify the file name in some way ?

```
proc check_file_exists {name} {
   upvar $name newName
   check_exists $name     #Do all checks that file is there
   set newName $name_1
}

check_file_exists $name
puts $name
```

this code will print the old name of the file and not the new one.

Comment: If you don't know the name, you cannot modify the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you should do is bite the bullet and change the calls. It's a fairly simple search-and-replace, after all. The code will be more sane than if you use any of the other solutions.

```
check_file_exists name
```

Or, you could add another parameter to the parameter list and use that to pass the name, making the first argument a dummy argument.

```
check_file_exists $name name
```

Or, if you're not using the return value, you could return the new value and assign it back:

```
set name [check_file_exists $name]
```

Or, you could assign the new value to a global variable (e.g. `theValue`) inside the procedure, and assign *that* back:

```
check_file_exists $name
# don't need this if you're in global scope
global theValue
set name $theValue
```

Or, you could assign the name to a global variable (e.g. `theName`) and access that inside the procedure: the procedure will be able to update `name` directly.

```
# don't need this if you're in global scope
global theName
set theName name
check_file_exists $name
```

(There are some variations on this f.i. using `upvar`.)

None of the alternatives are pretty, and all of them still require you to make a change at the call (except the last, if you only ever use one variable for this value). If you're adamant about not doing that, there's always Donal's `info frame` solution, which only requires the procedure itself to be changed.

Let me know if you want help with the procedure code for any of these alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite difficult; it's really not the way you're supposed to work. *But* you can do it using `info frame -1` (a facility usually used for debugging) to find out exactly how the current procedure was called. However, you need to be careful as the caller might be using the result of a command: *this is an unsafe hack*.

```
proc check_file_exists {name} {
    set caller [dict get [info frame -1] cmd]
    if {[regexp {^check_file_exists +\$(\w+)} $caller -> varName]} {
        # OK, we were called with a simple variable name
        puts "Called with variable $varName"
    } else {
        # Complicated case! Help...
        return -code error "must be called with a simple variable's contents"
    }

    upvar 1 $varName newName
    check_exists $name
    set newName $name_1
}
```

Comment: If the name of the variable is already known, `upvar varname localname` can also do the job. Opens a can of worms.

Comment: This whole area is multiple high-pressure cans of worms. “I cannot change what is passed” is usually a sign that some deeply wrong way of working is about to be attempted.